Aws Sagemaker Notebook Instance cell stop while execution
I want to train yolov8 on aws sagemaker notebook but the cell is stopping automatically after 2 epochs
enter image description here
The notebook cell should not stop unless I stop it. But it is suddenly stopping.
I need help with this issue.

Are you on the notebook browser tab while the cell is running? If the browser tab is closed and reopened, it's possible that you miss the outputs. Try writing the outputs to the file. Otherwise, is it possible that the kernel dies because of out of memory? You can try resizing the notebook and retrying the cell.
